# When turned on the lap after updating ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 it shows error

Tags: boot, software-installation, bootloader

This is the error message I got. Can it be fixed?

[image]

```
[8.495885] Initramfs unpacking failed: invalid magic at start of compressed archive
[8.683497] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unkno
wn-block(0,0)
8.6835881 CPU: 1 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.4.0-53-generic #59-Ubuntu
[8.683666] Hardware name: HP HP Notebook/81F1, BIOS F.21 10/27/2016
[0.683742] Call Trace:
[0.683825] dump_stack+0x6d/0x9a
[0.683905] panic+0x101/0x2e3
[0.683977] mount_block_root+0x23f/0x2e8
[0.684047] mount_root+0x38/0x3a
[0.684116] prepare_namespace+0x13f/0x194
[0.684186] kernel_init_freeable+0x231/0x255
```

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucu9O.png